# Looking for a cordova keyboard plugin for IOS and android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, keyboard

i had researched for last few days about
cordova plug in for android and ios,... but im too confused ..

first iam not using ionic so far just cordova in intelxdk and using bs3
for UI,.. so as i know ... ionic keyboard plug in is not good idea...
i cant find usefull plugin  thats works with ios and android with good documentation

any help any idea
i appreciate.

Comment: why not using `ionic-plugin-keyboard`? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

Comment: i have used the ionic plugin and it worked really well, what do you need to do with it?

Comment: .maybe,  but i just want to make sure with you because all the plugin that i used are cordova plugin ,.. i thought maybe its not necessary  , .. does ionic keyboard work properly in ios? i can not figure it out .... in documentation there is not any problems with android device but its something else  for ios... how i cant show keyboard after user clicked event in ios... i didnt test its but for android we can use cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();